# Length of a For loop

Tags: procedural-programming

How to find the length of a For loop?
Here is a simple example:

```
For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[i]]

0

1

2

3
```

How to find that there are in total 4 outputs using the //Length function or similar.

Let me take an example for comparison:

```
tb = Table[x, {x, 1, 5, 1}]
Length[tb]
5
```

The problem is that I have long For loop defined which is almost impossible to copy here, bcz its too complicated. There is an iteration

```
i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[i]
```

defined inside the For loop. The actual problem in fractional, not integer as in the example above. I want know what is the length of the range between i = min and i = max just like we use "Length" for a table as shown above.

In the example above, obviously its 4, but how can we ask mathematica to find total number of outputs such as 4 for us.

Comment: The parameters of the For loop tell you this explicitly: `i = 0, i < 4, i++`. Surely you're asking something more than that, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I did not understand the question.  Are you asking how to obtain the number of Prints from the evaluation of a cell ? If so that is independent of  `For` and you could ask that question for any code. If you are asking how to programmatically get the number of iterations of a `For` loop that is held using `Hold`, then if the same structure as the one in the example you provided is being used, then one could use for example `Hold[For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[i]]][[1, 2, 2]]`. The reason for the part choice can be visualized using `For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[i]] // Hold // TreeForm`.

Comment: The For construct always produces Null, so there is no length to its output. If you're expecting your loop to terminate early, so that the iteration parameters cannot be used to calculate what you want directly, then you could just inspect `i` after the loop is finished, and determine the number of iterations that way.

Comment: Maybe what you want is your own counter: `For[i = 0; counter = 0, i < 10, i += 3; counter++, Print[i]]`. I altered your example to have a case where the loop iterator didn't increment by one, and therefore doesn't reflect the number of iterations. When the loop is done, just inspect `counter`.

Comment: By the way it is recommended to use `Do` instead of `For` (in which case the code I provided before does not work). To see why`Do` is preferred there is this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134610/86543)

Comment: I appreciate that you're probably trying to simplify your real problem to be able to ask the question more clearly, but as it stands, it doesn't really make much sense. I think giving us a bit more context--what you're actually trying to count--would help immensely.

Comment: Please see the appended part in body text.

Comment: `(Length@Trace[For[...], TraceDepth -> 3] - 4)/3`? If you want to predict the number of iterations, I doubt that is possible, since one may advance `i` in the body according to whatever condition, even `WeatherData[First@CityData["Kathmandu"], "Temperature"]`.

Comment: Okay, I see the update, but I still don't understand why you can't just compute what you desire. If your iteration parameters are `i = 0, i < 10, i+=.25`, then the total number of iterations is 40. If you don't want to calculate manually, then the formula would be `Celling[(max - min)/stepsize]`. Or, if you want to do it while the for loop is running, use the `counter` idea I posted above.

Comment: Also, you keep using the term "outputs". Does your for loop actually generate results? Why can't you apply Length to that?

Comment: Actually, maybe that's your question. Are you asking how to get an output from a For loop? You could try something like this: `output = {}; For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, AppendTo[output, i]]`. Then `output` would be `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, and you can just apply Length to it.

Comment: You could also Sow/Reap: `Reap[For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Sow[i]]]`. This gives `{Null, {{0, 1, 2, 3}}}` from which you can extract the "output" and check its length.

Comment: ``Internal`GetIteratorLength[{i, 0, 4}]`` assumes <=, not <. And ``Internal`GetIteratorLength[{i, 0, 4, 0.25}] - 1`` won't always work either.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Are these internal and developer context functions categorized somewhere or does one have to memorize them all ? Also how does one find them and how many different hidden contexts like this are there ? Maybe I should ask in a separate question if this has not already been asked (I know there is a question about which ones are useful).

Comment: @userrandrand See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions.  But I just remember that one.  It may or may not be in that Q&A.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yep i think that is the one I had in mind thanks. It's quite daunting to scroll through as some answers are  specific to one context and others are on a bunch of hidden functions with hyperlinks. The one with Internal`GetIteratorLength is one that you posted it seems.

Comment: OP might also be interested in a progress bar

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps OP would like something to monitor the computation. I am guessing that is also why there was `Print` in the question. One could use a counter or `Reap` and `Sow` as @lericr suggested in the comments. If OP is willing to use `Do` instead of `For` then OP could use for example [MonitorProgress](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MonitorProgress/) from the resource function repository (**Note :** Resource functions might not be as reliable as native functions as they are not necessarily made by members of the Wolfram team, you can check the source notebook of the function for how it was made):

For example,

```
ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"]@Do[i += 5; Pause[1], {i, 1, 8, 0.5}]
```

[image]

That image shows the total number of evaluations that will be needed next to Progress  (15). With `For` it did not show the total number of computations.

One problem might be that you would have to visually register the total number of computations. That could be tedious to write down or difficult to see when the evaluation is fast. In that case one might want to consider the counter method by @lericr and maybe also monitor the counter with [`Monitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html).

Resource functions can be stored locally on the computer with `ResourceFunction["PersistResourceFunction"]`. For example, after evaluating

```
ResourceFunction["PersistResourceFunction"]["MonitorProgress"]
```

One can then find MonitorProgress by just typing Mo and the function will appear from the autocomplete menu. Then it's as simple as `MonitorProgress@Do[i += 5; Pause[1], {i, 1, 8, 0.5}]`. That said, it is unclear to me what happens if in a future version of Mathematica a function has the same name.